# How to install Tv-maxe

Tags: 12.04, installation, dependencies

I am having problems install TV-MAXE on one laptop the issue is that is asking for ubuntu 12.04 lts cd to be in /cdrom/.

Apparently the issue are the files lirc and setserial that will not install,tried with command line,synaptic and software center,mounted ubuntu iso on /media,/cdrom,/home(default of furius iso),mounted live usb and still it will not install the files.
I have the ppa installed for tv-maxe and internet connection.

Any workarounds?

Comment: TV-MAXE full installation apparently works on other machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install TV-MAXE on Ubuntu using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:venerix/pkg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tv-maxe
```

Comment: I used this ppa "ppa:trebelnik-stefina/tv-maxe" because the ppa from venerix did not worked for me the first time I installed tv-maxe

Comment: @adi: and now TV-MAXE it's working for you?

Comment: I have installed tv-maxe with stefina ppa on one machine, and on the one which didn't worked installation before it worked with this ppa, strange stuff